# Compare list within dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two dictionaries with a list in the value part. Something like this

```
dict1 = {red:[1,2,3], blue:[7,6,9], green:[3,9,3,1]}
dict2 = {red:[2,1,3], blue:[9,7,6], green:[3,9,1,3]}
```

In this case, the comparison must give a **True** as in both the dictionaries contains the same values in the list for a given key. I come up with a solution in which I access the list values using the key. Then check if the length of the lists are same and each value in one list present in the other list.
I think there is some other way to do this in python. What is the best "pythonic" way to do this?

Comment: So basically comparing the lists without regard to order?

Comment: Yes, but it is lists inside a dictionary

Comment: @aaroh then just add an extra layer of checks for the dictionary keys.

Comment: @aaroh You can try it: rslt= len(dict1)==len(dict2) and all( k1==k2 and sorted(l1)==sorted(l2) for (k1,l1),(k2,l2) in zip(sorted(dict2.items()),sorted(dict1.items())) )

Comment: `list(map(sorted, dict1.values())) == list(map(sorted, dict2.values()))` ?

Comment: @kantal: there is no need to sort, and certainly not twice.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: `Counter(a) == Counter(b)` lets you do the same test O(N) time. Don't use sorting unless the values are not hashable.

Comment: Python 2 solution: `from collections import Counter`, then `a.viewkeys() == b.viewkeys() and all(Counter(v) == Counter(b[k]) for k, v in a.iteritems())`. This solves the issue in O(N) time, where `N` is the total number of entries in all lists, with an early exit whenever it is found that keys don't match or any of the value lists are not equal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters like `list(map(Counter, dict1.values())) == list(map(Counter, dict2.values()))` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: This is Python 2, so `map()` doesn't need `list()`. And you are assuming that the keys are going to be listed in the same order, which they often will not.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: you need to test if the keys are equal first too. `a.viewkeys() == b.viewkeys()` does a set comparison between the two key collections, efficiently. Then you need to ensure that you compare the counters *per paired key*. And you want to exit early if there is a mismatch, and avoid creating more `Counter()` objects when you already know the answer, hence the use of `all()`.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters "there is no need to sort, and certainly not twice." sorted(dict1.items()) sorts really by the keys only for pairing in zip(), and sorted(l1) sorts by the value(i.e.sublist).

Comment: @kantal: yes, I know. You don't need to sort the keys, because you can loop over the keys of one dict to look them up in the other. And you don't need to sort the values, because counting them instead in O(N) time would suffice.

Comment: @aaroh: that's not something I can help with, because the code I posted can't throw that error and I can't see what code you are using that throws that error. That error is not specific to using a `Counter()`.

Comment: @aaroh: if you are having trouble implementing the suggestions made, you could post a new question with a [mcve] that reproduces the problem so we can help.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters "Don't use sorting unless the values are not hashable."  This is the point, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {"red": [1, 2, 3], "blue": [7, 6, 9], "green": [3, 9, 3, 1]}
dict2 = {"red": [2, 1, 3], "blue": [9, 7, 6], "green": [3, 9, 1, 3]}


def compare_dicts(a, b):
    if set(a.keys()) != set(b.keys()):
        # If the keys do not match,
        # the dicts can't be equal.
        return False

    for key, value in a.items():
        if key not in b:
            # If a key does not exist in `b`,
            # but exists in `a`, the dicts
            # can't be equal.
            return False

        if sorted(value) != sorted(b[key]):
            # If the sorted lists of values aren't
            # equal, the dicts can't be equal.
            return False

            # Every other case failed to exit, so the dicts
            # must be equal.
    return True


print(compare_dicts(dict1, dict2))
```

Comment: Sorting means I am increasing the complexity, is there any better way?

Comment: Don't use sorting, use `collection.Counter` objects: `Counter(value) != Counter(b[key])`. And don't use `set()` objects, Python [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) are sets and can be compared directly: `a.viewkeys() != b.viewkeys()`.

Comment: Your `if key not in b:` test is redundant, you already determined that the keys in both dictionaries match. Do not use `a.items()` in Python 2, use `a.iteritems()` or `a.viewitems()`.

Comment: `return a.viewkeys() == b.viewkeys() and all(Counter(v) == Counter(b[k]) for k, v in a.iteritems())` suffices.

Answer (score -1):

If you wish compare two lists ignoring values order, you can convert each list to set

```
set(list1) == set(list2)
```

Comment: This assumes the values in each list are unique. For lists with repeated values, this *ignores* the repetition counts!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `set` to compare two lists containing same elements but in different order

```
>>> dict1 = {'red':[1,2,3], 'blue':[7,6,9], 'green':[3,9,3,1]}
>>> dict2 = {'red':[2,1,3], 'blue':[9,7,6], 'green':[3,9,1,3]}
>>> all(set(v) == set(dict2.get(k)) for k,v in dict1.items())
True
```

If the dict values can be repeated, use `sorted` to compare

```
>>> all(sorted(v) == sorted(dict2.get(k)) for k,v in dict1.items())
True
```

Comment: This assumes the values in each list are unique. For lists with repeated values, this *ignores* the repetition counts!